# zend framework 2 notice appears in console when call a console action

Tags: console, zend-framework2, zend-controller, zend-controller-router

I have follow the simple steps of zend [documentation](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.console.controllers.html) to develop a many simple console action.

My action have only one literal param. It works ok and the action is executed but before, in each call appears following notice and a stack trace.

How I do for remove / solve this message

```
    Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE in C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc_desarrollo\module\SecureDraw\Module.php on line 124

    Call Stack:
        0.0003     121464   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc_desarrollo\public\index.php:0
        0.0079     237776   2. Zend\Mvc\Application::init() C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc_desarrollo\public\index.php:12
        0.1589    1822568   3. Zend\Mvc\Application->bootstrap() C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc_desarrollo\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php:239
        0.2135    2232464   4. Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger() C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc_desarrollo\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php:142
        0.2135    2232584   5. Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners() C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc_desarrollo\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:204
        0.2350    2387304   6. call_user_func() C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc_desarrollo\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:460
        0.2350    2387320   7. SecureDraw\Module->onBootstrap() C:\xampp\htdocs\pfc_desarrollo\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php:460
    --------------------------------HELLOOOOOO------------------
```

This is my action / route definition

```
    //module.php
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'hello' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => 'hello',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'SecureDraw\Controller\Participant',
                            'action'     => 'hello',
                        ),
                    ),
                ), //Line 124
            ),
        ),
    ),  

    //Participant.php
    public function helloAction(){
        return "--------------------------------HELLOOOOOO------------------";
    }
```

Comment: Is this `module.config.php` or really the Module-Class?

Comment: Is module.config.php, console array is in same level that controllers array, routes, etc.

Comment: The error is for #124 of Module.php - your Module class, check there ;)

Answer (score 1):

You must be trying to access the Server Variable HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE inside your Module.php file.

$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] is usally set using the Browser which has requested the page, but as your are running the app from the console it is probably not getting set.

You should check to see if it's set before accessing it.